# Several WebServers redundancy with same IP for the public access

Tags: debian, centos, ip, webserver, redundancy

We are using 2 (or even more) WebServers for backup, so if the main WebServer went down, the others will be replaced.

For this purpose, I think I should use Virtual IP address (Red triangle), right? If yes so, how should I set and do this? And if not, what is the best for this purpose, and how should I make it?

[image]

OS: Debian 8 & CentOS 7